# Configure Destination Domain to accept CNAME

Tags: configuration, dns, hosting, cpanel, cname

I'm currently having issues resolving CNAMEs that point my domain name. When a CNAME points to my domain name, it lands on the 404 error page that every new website has before contents are added.
In details: I have successfully created a CNAME record sample.origin.com to point to sample.destination.com. It hits sample.destination.com but displays a 404 error like sample.destination.com does not exist.

I think there is some configuration to be done on sample.destination.com that should accept the request from sample.origin.com.

I am quite certain about this because I have tried pointing a sample.origin.com to different destination domains and I get the default 404 page for such destination domains.
Any suggestion or help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your web server is expecting specific domain name, and the one you’re trying is not one of them.

Either add the domain to the list, provide redirection (application load balancer lister rule) or if the server us single domain, remove domain name so it will respond to all domains.